# Daydream's setting page is crashing on load

Tags: android, daydream

I am making a Plain Text Daydream on android and cannot open the settings screen. The rest of the daydream runs fine, but the settings don't. This is the settings xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="pref_text"
    android:title="Text on daydream"
    android:dialogTitle="Text on daydream:"
    android:defaultValue="Hello world!" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I'm using PreferenceFragments too. I assume it's the XML, but just in case here are the fragment and activity too:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
}
}
```

and

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
}
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Post your logcat then.

Comment: Logcat isn't showing anything but Dalvik attaching the debugger.

Comment: i got your issue you need to `extends` your `SettingsActivity` extends `PreferenceActivity` like `SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity` try this.

Comment: @SimplePlan Still crashing, and still nothing in the logcat but Dalvik attaching debugger.

Comment: Without Logcat we cant solve this issue.

Comment: Should I set settings as default activity and run it there?

Comment: Works perfectly that way, so I gues it might be the metadata that puts it in daydream. With it set that way, it opens in settings tooo. By that way I mean setting as default activity.

Comment: You are a Real Programmer becoz you solved your issue by your self.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was set the settings activity as the default. Then it's fixed!

Comment: +1 up from me without any HELP you got your solution.